# How to convert a nested list for the use in sklearn?

Tags: python, list

I have a long nested list in which each embedded list can have a different length or elements. I would like to flatten it in order to use each variable as a predictor in my model. The nested list looks like this:

```
  [[u'Burgers',u'Bars'],[u'Local Services', u'Dry Cleaning & Laundry'],[u'Shopping', u'Eyewear & Opticians'],[u'Restaurants'],...]
```

What I would like to achieve is something that I can use as a predictor in a model, especially in sklearn Machine Learning. The elements in the list should be used to predict the interested variable, which is the score. The desired result of the conversion would be like

```
[[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], ...]
```

Could someone give me a hand how to make this transformation? I am pretty stuck here. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pandas approach would be:

```
import pandas as pd
L = [['Burgers', 'Bars'], ['Local Services', 'Dry Cleaning & Laundry'], ['Shopping', 'Eyewear & Opticians'], ['Restaurants']]

ser = pd.Series([';'.join(i) for i in L]).str.get_dummies(';')
```

[image]

You can get the array with `.values`:

```
ser.values
array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]], dtype=int64)
```

This assumes you don't have `;` in those strings - you can change it with another separator. For scikit-learn you'd normally use [OneHotEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) but that also requires some preprocessing (label encoding first) so it seems easier with pandas.

Comment: Thank you so much for your assistance. This is very great!!

Answer (score 2):

You can first *flatten* the list then build the *scores* for the various *classes* from the *flattened* list, with a nested list comprehension by assigning `1` to values found in a given sublist (called `category`) and `0` if the *class* is not found

`Y` is the original list of classes to be predicted:

```
from itertools import chain

Y = [[u'Burgers',u'Bars'],[u'Local Services', u'Dry Cleaning & Laundry'],[u'Shopping', u'Eyewear & Opticians'],[u'Restaurants']]

classes = list(chain.from_iterable(Y))

scores = [[1 if c in category else 0 for c in classes] for category in Y]
print(scores)
# [[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am really learning a lot in this forum. There are so many talented!